# External hard drive slow after copying a few GB on first partition

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a new 4 TB hard drive (Toshiba Canvio Basics).
When I first tested it, it worked fine for copying approximately 2 GB of data at a reasonable speed (100-200 MB/s) via USB3. However, after about 2 GB, the speed dropped dramatically to a few KB/s. This also happens with a single large file. I tried it on both Linux and Windows (on different computers) and I also tried a different cable with the same results. Reformatting the entire drive to NTFS did also not help. Windows' chkdsk did not fix it.

I then formatted the drive with an empty 10 GB partition at the start, followed by the remaining capacity (NTFS). On this partition, data transfer appears to work fine.

Is it safe to use this HDD, skipping the "faulty" (?) part, or should I replace it entirely?

Comment: Why not exchange it if it's still under warranty? There is no guarantee that an apparently healthy HDD today will work tomorrow morning. If data is very important to you take two(double redundancy) back ups.

Comment: ...one onsite and one offsite https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/3-2-1-backup-rule.png

Comment: You are entirely correct, of course. I'll get a second drive and probably replace the first one.